# Need help in replacing detailViewController with Other ViewController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I am working on UISplitViewController for my app.

I am following a tutorial of SplitViewController. But,I am facing issue in navigation. It is not working on DetailViewController when I am pushing viewController on detailView Controller then it is replacing the full screen instead of only DetailViewController due to which MasterViewController is also getting hide.

Does somebody aware of this issue?
If yes, then please lead me to right path.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling alot, I got the solution. Probably, It may not be the exact answer but it helped.

```
        UIViewController *navigationViewController = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:navigationViewController, controller, nil];
        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
```